# Unique combination of two columns with mixed values

Tags: python, pandas, combinations

I have two columns with col1 and col2

[image]

I'm trying to create the key column to show that **a** and **b** is the same as **b** and **a**

Problem code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['a','c','b','e'],
              'Col2':['b','d','a','f']})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use numpy to sort and then join/sum the strings. This creates a unique key regardless of the order the values appear across columns.

```
import numpy as np

df['key'] = np.sort(df.to_numpy(), axis=1).sum(1)

#  Col1 Col2 key
#0    a    b  ab
#1    c    d  cd
#2    b    a  ab
#3    e    f  ef
```

---

In case you're interested `numpy.sort` is the performant way to do this. Any `.agg` or `.apply` reduce to slow loops over the rows so they will scale worse as the DataFrame becomes larger. Relative to `numpy.sort` the other methods are generally at least an order of magnitude slower.

```
import perfplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_lowercase


def apply_sorted(df):
    return df.apply(sorted, 1).str.join(sep='')

def numpy_sort(df):
    return pd.Series(np.sort(df.to_numpy(), axis=1).sum(1))


perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda N: pd.DataFrame({'Col1': np.random.choice([*ascii_lowercase], N), 
                                  'Col2': np.random.choice([*ascii_lowercase], N)}),
    kernels=[
        lambda df: apply_sorted(df),
        lambda df: numpy_sort(df),
    ],
    labels=['apply_sorted', 'numpy_sort'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(25)],
    equality_check=lambda x,y: x.compare(y).empty,
    relative_to=1,
    xlabel='len(df)'
)
```

[image]

Comment: yeah numpy sort does work. I tried a solution involving a apply lambda and that was taking half as long as frozenset.

Comment: Is there a way to modify this solution if I have more than two columns in my original dataframe?

Answer (score 4):

Try with `frozenset`

```
df['out'] = df.agg(frozenset,1).str.join(sep='')
Out[220]: 
0    ab
1    dc
2    ab
3    ef
dtype: object
```

Comment: Hmmm, this gives me an error with 1.3.0, `TypeError: 'frozenset' type is unordered`, but works on 1.2.2

Comment: It worked for me, but `df.agg(frozenset, axis=1).apply(sorted).str.join('')` might be better for sorting because it gave "ba" instead of "ab" for me

Comment: @ALollz interesting ~ let me find the release note  to see what happen ~

Answer (score 1):

I would use `sorted` built-in functions for this task following way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['a','c','b','e'],'Col2':['b','d','a','f']})
df['key'] = df.apply(sorted,1).str.join(sep='')
print(df)
```

output

```
  Col1 Col2 key
0    a    b  ab
1    c    d  cd
2    b    a  ab
3    e    f  ef
```

Explanation: it does sort every row lexicographically then join such elements. Assumption: every element of `Col1` is single character and every element of `Col2` is single character.